# wordpress sites get hacked

Tags: hacked

I have multiple sites on one shared hosting. The hosting provider told me that he deleted files that [were] malicious. After that all php files in `wp-content` & `wp-admin` returns 403 error even they have the right permission, so I cannot use any items in nav-bar of WordPress's panel. Also `.htacess`  of all WordPress files, if I edit, return to strange code like that:

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php|wp-l0gin.php|wp-theme.php|wp-scripts.php|wp-editor.php|mah.php|jp.php|ext.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Sites work fine in frontend but I cannot edit or make pages or posts or even run plugins.

Comment: You may need to hire a security company if your host doesn't fix it for you. Hacks often leave open holes to exploit. Specific recommendations would be off-topic, but if you look into popular security plugins, most offer hacking cleanup services as well.